# How to add custom event listener of v-select (Vuetify) change using derective?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have v-select element

```
<v-select
 :items="[1, 2, 3]"
 label="Some items"
 v-mydirective
></v-select>
```

And directive:

```
Vue.directive("mydirective", {
  bind: function(el, binding) {
    el.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      console.log("clicked");
    });
  }
});
```

When I click on Select, the message "clicked" will appear in console, but if I choose some item in items list it won't.
I want not only call function in derictive when item selected, but also pass selected item to this function in derective.

Is there a way to do this?

UPD: After some comments, I want to add:

I know, that i can simply do

```
<v-select
 :items="[1, 2, 3]"
 label="Some items"
 @input="someFunc"
></v-select>
```

but that is not what I need. I have to do directive.

"change" event doesn't work

Comment: Instead of `click`, listen for `change` event

Answer (score 0):

No need to create a custom directive for that. You already have events sent on click and on select:

````html
<v-select
 :items="[1, 2, 3]"
 label="Some items"
 @click="doSomeThing"
 @change="doSomeThing"
></v-select>
```
````

Comment: Thank you, but I know about that and about "@input",  but I need custom event anyway

Comment: Adding a directive on a component results on adding your directive to the root element inside the component. So if you don't know how the component is implemented, it's hard to create a custom behaviour...  
My guess would be to go through `el` childs until you find the `select` element and attach a `change` event listener to it.

Comment: @Виктор No need for `@input`, you can use `v-model` to bind to a variable

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved the next way:

```
Vue.directive("mydirective", {
  bind: function(el, binding, vnode) {
    if (vnode.componentInstance)
      vnode.componentInstance.$on("input", function(item) {
        console.log("input item: ", item);
      });
  }
});
```